# how to find selected hyperlink in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a list of 10 hyperlink on default1.apx. On selecting any hyperlink it redirects to another page and all hyperlinks redirects to the same page default2.aspx. But how can i now which hyperlink is clicked from 10 hyperlinks list in asp.net using C#.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways, all depending on how you're doing your redirect.

I'm guessing you're using `Response.Redirect()`, which means you must be raising a server side event when clicking. In this case all you need to do is check the `sender` argument which will give you details of which control was clicked.

Another way is to append the controls' name onto the URL in a GET request.  So that each link is slightly different.  For example link one could point to `default2.aspx?linkthatwasclicked='link1'` where you can substiute `link1` accordingly, this value can then be retreived on default2.aspx through the [Request.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) object.

Answer (score 0):

m.edmondson has got it, another way I've seen is having a "hyperlink.aspx" page which then requests an id:

```
<a href="hyperlink.aspx?id=1">Link 1</a>
```

then in the hyperlink.aspx code:

```
int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
switch(id)
{
    case 1:
    // Add a count to a table maybe
    // Get the url from the DB here...
    string url = GetUrlById(id);
    Response.Redirect(url);
    break;
}
```